# How to plot the fitted line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Plot these data and the fitted line.

```
x <- c(25, 50, 100, 150, 155, 187, 200, 237, 287, 290, 300)

y <- c(6.13, 5.51, 6.18, 6.70, 7.22, 7.28, 7.22, 7.48, 7.38, 7.38, 7.64)
```

My fitted line is y=-436.845+0.006266667x. How to draw these points and the fitted line in the same graph?

I need to specify the line  y=-436.845+0.006266667x, not any other line. Because I use nonparametric method to derive the line. I need to know how well this method works.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including your code in the question. This makes the context more obvious and makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: I already give the x and y vector. No other codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R graphics you could do this:

Note I've added the `ylim` argument to make the y scale capture the disparate values from the two sets of data.

```r
plot(x, y, ylim = c(-500, 20))

lines(x, y1, type = "l")
```

**data**

```r
x <- c(25, 50, 100, 150, 155, 187, 200, 237, 287, 290, 300)
y <- c(6.13, 5.51, 6.18, 6.70, 7.22, 7.28, 7.22, 7.48, 7.38, 7.38, 7.64)
y1 <- -436.845+0.006266667*x
```

**output**
[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your line equation does not match the data at all.  Even by eye you can tell, as the y intercept of about -436 places it very far from the y value of any of your points.

With that being said, here's how you can both find the "fitted" linear equation, given the data and then plot that line.  There's the short way and the "long" way.  Both have their advantages depending on the situation, so I'll show you both on your data.

#### Finding the fit using `lm()`

A simple way to find a linear regression line given a set of data is to use `lm()`.  Specify the general formula and the data, and there you go.  In your data, it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x <- c(25, 50, 100, 150, 155, 187, 200, 237, 287, 290, 300),
  y <- c(6.13, 5.51, 6.18, 6.70, 7.22, 7.28, 7.22, 7.48, 7.38, 7.38, 7.64)
)

fitted_fun <- lm(data=df, formula=y~x)
```

If you type `fitted_fun` into your console, you get the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   5.744474     0.006527
```

That's a very reasonable equation for a regression line based on that data.  In y=mx+b format, it would look like `y = (0.006527)x + 5.744474`.

#### Plotting

Based on the lack of `ggplot2` code in your question and given the context, it seems you're a bit new to using `ggplot2` for plotting as well.  There's lots of resources available online to help you get started, but suffice it to say, I'll give you the super brief rundown.

You'll need to indicate generally 3 things:

1. The **data** - dataset must be in the form of a data frame or be able to be coerced into a data frame.
2. The **aesthetics**.  Anything that is mapped to your data is an aesthetic, and these are mapped to columns in your dataframe.  So, you would have one column you indicate is associated to the x axis, one to the y, one that tells `ggplot` how to color a point, how to change the shape of a point, etc.
3. The **geoms**.  These are the things that are drawn on the plot *using* the data.  This could be a line, some points, a polygon (drawn to specifications based on that is in your data), some bars/columns... etc.

So, if you want to draw a plot with points and a line, you'll need `ggplot()` as a calling method, which includes a specification for aesthetics - indicated inside `aes()`.  You'll then need to use the `+` operator to link together the other plotting commands which correspond to the geoms:  `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`.  Since the points and the lines are using the same aesthetics (x and y), I will specify them inside of `ggplot()`.

You can draw the line by specifying to connect points in your data (not what you want here) or specify an equation to use (which is what you want here).  First, you need to write out your equation as a `function()`, then you can call that function to draw the line in the `geom_line`:

```
# using the coefficients named vector to pull the numbers, you can copy
# these out manually though
lm_func <- function(x) { fitted_fun$coefficients["(Intercept)"] + (fitted_fun$coefficients["x"] * x)}

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(stat="function", fun=lm_func, color='blue')
```

[image]

#### Simplification: Use `geom_smooth()`

We used `lm()` to fit a linear regression to the data, then put that in the form of a function, then used that function to draw a line.  It turns out, you can do this entirely in one step using another geom: `geom_smooth()`.  If you don't care about the equation of the line, but just want it to appear in your data, you can skip over the first two steps and just plot directly using the data frame.  I just need to specify that I want to use the `lm()` function as the `method=` inside of the `geom_smooth()` geom call:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method='lm', color='red', alpha=0.2) +  # note I'm also specifying alpha here for the fill
  theme_bw()    # just for a different look
```

[image]

#### Your Line Equation

So, want to see what your equation looks like?  Now you know how to do it (it's not an equation fit to the data, though).  First we'll setup a function using your line data, then we'll use that function and create a line:

my_function <- function(x) { -436.845 + (0.006266667*x)}

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(stat="function", fun=my_function, color='steelblue', linetype='dashed') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]